# Golang Bluetooth adapter.Scan stops by itself

Tags: go, bluetooth, tinygo

I am using the [tinygo-org/bluetooth](https://github.com/tinygo-org/bluetooth) package. When I run the scanner in the [example](https://github.com/tinygo-org/bluetooth#bluetooth-low-energy-central), after a while the panic drops. I can't find the cause, does anyone have any idea what it could be? Thanks.

[image: error]

Comment: What hardware/OS are you running this on?

Comment: @ukBaz thank you for your concern. I am testing on Windows 10 and on my laptop's built-in intel bluetooth module.

Addendum: I did the power configuration for the module in windows. I set it so that it never goes to sleep.